# Workflow taking long time and adding lots of major versions

Tags: workflow, version-history

I set up a simple workflow, if it is modified by a certain person it is to go to approval status, if they make a certain comment it is rejected. It is set up this way because there are a lot of initial documents to approve and they want to do as little as possible. I should have been suspicious when the workflow was taking about 5 minutes to run, when it is finished there are many major versions in the version history. Sometimes a dozen sometimes more (I've seen over 30). What can I do to get this working right? or better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest to an answer if there is any one interested. What I have done is added a pause for a 1 minute duration after I set the content approval status to approved and after I use stop the workflow. I also added set content approval to pending 1st, then a 1 minute pause, then content approval to approved, then a 1 minute pause. It takes a while, but it only leaves one minor version for pending and then 1 major version for approval and then I use stop the workflow. Before it was leaving multiple versions. Not sure if I need the pending, but I need the pause and the stop. Don't know why it works, but so far it has been working.